# Get tags name under custom taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

I want to get/show only available tags under custom taxonomy. Here's my code;

```
$tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); // print current taxonomy 

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'types', // CPT
    'taxonomy' => $tax->slug, //get current taxonomy page
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty' => false
); 

$tags = get_tags( $args );
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    echo '<li>'.$tag->name.'</li>';
}
```

My problem is in other page which don't have the tags under the taxonomy always shows. Any suggestion to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get all tags in a taxonomy.

```
<?php

$tags = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy',
    )
);

foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
    echo $tag->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tags of current post using:

```
$tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); // print current taxonomy 

$args = array( 
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

if( 'types' == get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) ) {
    $tags = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(),  $tax->slug, );
    if ( ! empty( $tags ) ) {
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ) {
            foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
                echo '<li>'.esc_html( $tag->name ).'</li>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```